# Juicebox wordpress plugin is not working properly

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I've created gallery using Juicebox wordpress plugin step by step. But as you can see on this website http://vevi-wedding-photography.co.uk/pph-test/
it's automatically set to display:none in css element.style.

Do you have any ideas why it's set to display:none ?